# Self table comparison

Tags: oracle

I Have a table emp which has

```
ename sal
Smith 1000
Mark  2000
Jack  500
```

The output should be(person earning lower salary on the left)

```
Jack Smith
Jack Mark
Smith Mark
```

Please help

Comment: PLease format your data so it is readable as a table.  What have you attempted?

Comment: I don't see how you get the third row of data in your output.  I assume that is the row in the output that corresponds to the "Jack" row of the input but it doesn't have Jack's information at all.  Should the person with the lowest salary appear in the first column of every row in the output other than the one for the lowest salary employee?  That would be a weird result set.  What happens if there is a tie?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a cross join with a filter.

```
select h1.ename as first, h2.ename as second
from have as h1 
cross join have as h2 
where h1.sal>h2.sal
```